# Problems with loading chrome browser using selenium web driver

Tags: java, google-chrome

i am not able to run my tests in chrome browser.i am using selenium-java 2.33.0 and java for coding.

Below are the steps

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

it opens the chrome browser and throws the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:     Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c187d01409a5dc3b7f8251859150c8af0bcb', time: '2013-04-09 10:39:28'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.4', java.version: '1.6.0_35'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
at com.integration.RandomID.main(RandomID.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c187d01409a5dc3b7f8251859150c8af0bcb', time: '2013-04-09 10:39:28'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.4', java.version: '1.6.0_35'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:17036/status] to be available after 20018 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:228)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
... 10 more
```

Where am i going wrong?

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: It indicates that driver cannot reach the link `http://localhost:17036/status`, it could be due to the port, the OS might have used the port already for some other purpose. Try restarting your machine.

Comment: @SajanChandran i tried restarting my machine as well but found No luck :(

Comment: You need to download the Chrome driver
https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list And specify it for your webdriver.chrome.driver var

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do not use your Chrome binary that you browse the internet with. Download it from the [Chromedriver website](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), and specify the path to that in your code.

This link has the solution explained in more detail: http://www.gjdb.nl/?p=214:

> When you want to run Chrome on WebDriver for your Mac, then according to according to the site http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver you will need to specify the path to the browser to the following location: “/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome”.
>
> So the Java code for creating a ChromeDriver instance will be:
>
> ```java
> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
> driver = new ChromeDriver();
> ```
>
> When trying to run this I got the following exception.
>
> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
> Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d185a80fa4206dfeab80ba773c04ac33c0', time: '2013-02-27 13:51:26'
> System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.3', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
> ...
> ```
>
> This I fixed by using the ChromeDriver. Download your version on http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list, unzip it and use it as followed:
>
> ```java
> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<unzip location>/chromedriver");
> driver = new ChromeDriver();
> ```

Comment: Note you still need to install Chrome on your machine. The driver is just a wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Search for chrome.exe in your start search, copy the file location & give it in the url:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".....AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
WebDriver wcr = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: the OP is on Mac OS X not on Windows